# Bootstrap sidebars rendered by Flask don't collapse

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-5

I am creating a Flask Web App and I want to use a Bootstrap 5.0 sidebar so I went to Bootstrap example page and downloaded the example that fits my needs. The plain HTML/CSS/JS file works fine. If you click on the buttom in the left of first level options the second level colapse/expand automatically. But when I call the same HTML file using render_template Flask function the colapse/expand don't work.

Here is the original HTML file (I removed a symbol svg session due to size limit here)

```
 <!doctype html> <html lang="en">   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.84.0">
    <title>Sidebars · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/">

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS --> <link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="sidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">   </head>   <body>

<main>   <h1 class="visually-hidden">Sidebars examples</h1>

  <div class="flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-white" style="width: 280px;">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="30" height="24"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
      <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Collapsible</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Home
        </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="link-dark rounded">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Updates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Reports</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Dashboard
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Weekly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Monthly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Annually</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#orders-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Orders
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="orders-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Processed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Shipped</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Returned</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Account
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Sign out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>   </div>

  <div class="b-example-divider"></div>

</main>


    <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

      <script src="sidebars.js"></script>   </body> </html>
```

My application is supposed to run on a intranet so I download all the css and js file and save them in the static folder of my Flask app and changed the references in HTML file which became this way.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.84.0">
    <title>Sidebars · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ url_for("static",filename="css/bootstrap.css" ) }}>

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ url_for("static",filename="css/sidebars.css" ) }}>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<main>
  <h1 class="visually-hidden">Sidebars examples</h1>

  <div class="flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-white" style="width: 280px;">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="30" height="24"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
      <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Collapsible</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Home
        </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="link-dark rounded">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Updates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Reports</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Dashboard
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Weekly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Monthly</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Annually</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#orders-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Orders
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="orders-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Processed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Shipped</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Returned</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          Account
        </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Sign out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="b-example-divider"></div>

</main>

<script src={{ url_for("static",filename="js/bootstrap.js" ) }}></script>
<script src={{ url_for("static",filename="js/bootstrap.bundle.js" ) }}></script>
<script src={{ url_for("static",filename="js/sidebar.js" ) }}></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the python files I use to create the app.

the **init**.py in the main folder to create the Blueprint.

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main',__name__)

from . import views
```

the **init**.py in the app folder

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_googlecharts import GoogleCharts

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
moment = Moment()

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug=True

    with app.app_context():
        bootstrap.init_app(app)
        moment.init_app(app)
        
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
 
    return app
```

and the view.py file

```
from flask import Flask,session,request,render_template,jsonify,url_for,redirect,flash
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from . import main

@main.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I didn't changed anything in the css/js from boostrap. Does anyone have ever seen something like that?

Comment: This does noty looks like a error on the python side or related to Flask at all. Try to check in your browser console if the bootstrap css is loaded ok and if there are any missing resources or errors

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. I found the problem and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Man. It is just because I spent 15 minutes writing a question and 5 minutes after I posted it I found the problem. The problem was these line in the second html file.

```
<script src={{ url_for("static",filename="js/bootstrap.js" ) }}></script>
```

I don't know why but this is unecessary and was causing some error on the page animation.